# How to replace 20A breaker with 15A breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

[image]
[image]
[image][image][image][image]I was recently updating a couple light fixtures in my house and I discovered both are supplied with 14 gauge wires. The circuit for the lights runs off a 20A breaker and contains receptacles as well. The receptacles are rated 15A and are wired with 12 gauge. I want to replace the 20A breaker with a 15A breaker in order to protect the 14 gauge wire to the lights. Can this be done by simply swapping in a compatible 15A breaker? Or is there more to it?

It's the two inner breakers that I need to downgrade; the outer ones protect circuits for the washer and kitchen receptacles, respectively, so I need to keep them.

[image]

Comment: I've added your pic linked in the comments below and the comment involved. This is a critical piece of information and changes everything. Also, I've updated my answer as it does _not_ apply to _your_ situation, though it's generally correct. I should have known better than to answer on partial info...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry I didn’t mention the tandem breakers. Since the other two circuits need a higher level of protection, I’ll need to keep two of the four 20A breakers. And that certainly does complicate this scenario. My apologies. My question now is: is it ok to rearrange the hot wires so that the two circuits with 20A breaker requirements remain on one of the existing tandem breakers? Or should I preserve the sequence/positioning by replacing both tandems with new tandem (split 15A/20A) breakers?

Comment: @Justin can you post a photo of the label on the inside of the panel's door please?

Comment: Hi @ThreePhaseEel. Is the label you're referencing the one in the picture at the top of my original post? That's the only label I see, but maybe I missed something. The label says Class CTL panel.

Comment: @Justin -- is there not a label on the door of the panel?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No label on the door. I found another label inside the left half of the box. Pic added above.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm guessing you're looking for a diagram of the panel and that's definitely not it.  Unfortunately, I don't see a diagram anywhere.

Comment: @Justin -- hrm.  are there any labels that might identify the make or model of the unit?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel There’s a sticker just above the main breaker. I added a photo above. Also, I can see the old glue on the door where the label was once attached. I’m guessing this box is as old as my house (1953), but I think the panel was installed in the early 90s.

Comment: You don’t need to change the breaker to the receptacles 2 ea or more 15a receptacles on a 20 amp circuit has been code legal for many decades , but the 14 gauge wire sure change those.,, if there are multiples of this a tandem 15 for those them moving other receptacles to 1/2 of the 20 the problem will be finding compatible 15a tandems

Comment: I just read the comments and saw the one asking about doing what I recommended +. absolutely you can move circuits. if the hot wires are not long enough a new piece of wire can be tied to the existing with a wire nut or a lever lock long enough to make it to the other breaker. Then relabel the panel card for the circuits that were moved, turn off each breaker before removing the wires or adding to a breaker.  Some will say to turn the main off before adding or removing breakers I have been doing this professionally since the 70’s and was taught to just turn the branch circuit breaker prior.

Comment: @EdBeal Great, thanks for the responses.  So, if I understand you correctly, I can keep one of the original 20A tandem breakers, rearrange the wires in the panel so that the washer and kitchen receptacle circuits are on it? Then I can connect the two circuits with 14 gauge wiring to a new 15A tandem? It's just a matter of finding the right 15A tandem (to replace one of the 20A tandems) and rearranging the hot wires in the panel, right?

Comment: Yes you can do that, it looked like a few circuits were shut down at the bottom so putting 15 amp breakers down there may also be an option. Splicing in the breaker panel to extend a wire to the correct breaker size is code compliant. In some jurisdictions making these corrections, not adding branch circuits but downsizing to the proper size may not require a permit. I would take a photo of the panel and circuit directory, change the 2 to the proper size update the directory and take additional photos. If the # of circuits is on file and correct this would be where a permit would not be needed

Comment: @EdBeal Ok, thanks again. I'm going to follow your recommendation to rearrange the circuits and replace one of the 20A tandem breakers with a 15. You mentioned it might be difficult to find a compatible 15A tandem for my panel. Should I be looking for a Cutler Hammer BR "cheater" type without the physical restrictions?

Comment: Does the OP know where the wire changes from #12 to #14? Would this have been done in the original wiring or was this a retrofit extension of the circuit to accomodate added lights?

Comment: @JimStewart Every light in the house (except one) is wired with 14 gauge. Fortunately, almost all of them are on just 3 circuits. One of the circuits is protected by a 15 amp breaker. The other 2 are the ones in question. There are 7 lighting fixtures total on these circuits and one of the fixtures is on a 3-way switch (in the hall).  I was hoping to just swap the breaker and avoid having to re-wire all the lights.

Answer (score 4):

### Wait. Did you say "INNER"?

There is a scheme called a "Multi-Wire Branch Circuit"  or MWBC where /3 cable is used, and they share the neutral.  This will overload the neutral (obviously!) ...  *unless* the 2 hot wires are placed in a very particular way.  Specifically, the 2 hot wires must be on opposite *poles* so they are 240V apart.

When you said "Inner", my thinking is that these might be a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit.   If so, not only must you place the wires correctly, but you must also use a "Handle tied" breaker.  In the tandem world, this is a "Quadplex" such as a BQ215220. (which has the 15's on the *outer* so you'd have to change that up).

Assuming they are in fact MWBCs, and I need you to check, the terrible thing would be to buy a 1515 tandem and move the two 20s to a single tandem and move the two 15's to the other tandem.  That would result in 0V between the hot wires, and overloading of the neutral.

I'm not sure that's the case for you, but you should really find out!

### Why do you think it is 15A wire?

I ask because until recently, *all* Romex cables were white.  If you're looking at white jacketed romex and thinking "white = #14" that is incorrect.  You need to read the labeling on the cable jacket.

Comment: So, each breaker on my panel turns off a specific group of receptacles/switches independently. And no receptacle or switch requires two breakers to be shut off. If I understand the MWBC logic correctly, this means there are no MWBC circuits.

Comment: The 14 gauge wire is in the electrical boxes for my light switches. I verified it's size by comparing it with the (slightly larger) 12 gauge wire that exists elsewhere in my house. I had a spare piece of light blue 12/2 that I used for comparison. I also used a nickel and dime to verify the two sizes independently.

Comment: @Justin No, MWBCs do not work like that.  They behave exactly like independent circuits, and you wouldn't know unless you opened all the boxes and saw where 2 hots were sharing a neutral - which might only be in 1 place!  You have to follow the wires and see if the cable leaving the panel is a /3 cable (black and red and white).

Comment: Ok. All the wires going into the two adjacent tandems are black. And none of them are spliced.

Comment: The two "outer" circuits (which I need to remain protected at 20A) are: 1. dedicated for the washer 2. two duplex receptacles - one in the corner of the kitchen (not countertop), and the other on the opposite side of the wall in the corner of the living room

Comment: @Justin Follow the hot wires from the breakers themselves to where they enter the edge of the panel from a cable or conduit.  Make sure each hot has a partner neutral.  Like I say, MWBCs can "mimic" regular circuits in all respects except for what I just said.

Comment: Ok, going to look right now. Thanks for catching this possible risk and alerting me.

Comment: Also, would the red wire from the /3 be in one of the electrical boxes inside? There are only 3 receptacles on these two circuits combined.  I opened them a few days ago when I was hunting for 14 gauge everywhere in my house. I didn't notice any red wire, but I will double check.

Comment: @Justin if you check in the panel (where the wire comes out of the cable) that is pretty much canonical.  If you confirm independent neutrals there, you need look no further.

Comment: Ok, so I tried checking for 12/3 where the wires enter the box, but I can’t access that particular area (in the bottom at the back). I can follow the hots down to a certain point, but then it’s just too crowded. There are dozens of 12 gauge wires in that area and none of the cable is visible. It’s a total mess. (Pic added above). Is there a way to eliminate the MWBC possibility from the receptacles instead?

Comment: I went ahead and opened the electrical boxes for all 3 receptacles on the two "outer" circuits.  I located the "line" wire for the first receptacle on each circuit. Both were 12/2 (I didn't find any 12/3 in the outlet boxes). My premonition says these are not MWBC circuits -- but I want to be certain. How likely could it be in these scenarios that a junction box may exist somewhere inconspicuous (e.g. the crawl space above the ceiling)?

Answer (score 0):

## Warning!

While this answer is generally correct, it is **NOT** correct for the OP's situation. The picture of the tandem breaker was added *after* this answer was written and up voted.

---

---

Yes, with the correct 15A breaker for your panel, you can simply swap a 15A for 20A breaker. If the existing breaker is AFCI and/or GFCI, it's highly recommended to replace it with a new breaker with identical functions, as there's likely a good reason for it to be there.

Be sure you're comfortable working with the cover off of the breaker panel - there's a lot of danger in there if you're not careful. I'd strongly recommend having someone there with you, just in case.

NOTE: If you're renting, this is *NOT* something you're legally allowed to do, nor is the property owner. It *must* be done by a licensed electrician. This is for both your protection and the landlord's.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One of the fixtures is in the kitchen, but the receptacles and remaining fixture are in the family room. I also have an identical problem with a circuit that spans two bedrooms (7 receptacles, 3 light fixtures). I think the breakers are fairly old. Both belong to separate tandem sets (with 2 breakers in each slot.) I don’t see AFCI/GFCI listed on either breaker. Does the kitchen fixture require a GFCI breaker?

Comment: Kitchen receptacles should be gfci (either at the receptacle itself or at the breaker), but fixtures don't have to be gfci. Post a pic or two of your panel and you'll get information about the breakers. (Hint: some are bad.)

Comment: Additional tip: when you change breakers, it's a really good idea to use a torque screwdriver to tighten the wire down. If you can't find one to borrow, basic ones aren't terribly expensive.

Comment: Thanks Aloysius. Here's a photo of the breakers: ![Valid XHTML](https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/284792720_109734645086304_4369000743345241699_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5b7eaf&_nc_ohc=GgDkI849PfQAX9taDBQ&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=00_AT95cHA4eEkcAQuo6xleGUJn5yLyCym90lttzrPTZ-J6TA&oe=629721FD) ![Valid XHTML](https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/284606622_109735201752915_4709361603338793150_n.jpg?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=5b7eaf&_nc_ohc=DM8rCzWqPSoAX-Qnl8Y&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=00_AT_kZQRK8XvD8uHTZHdRLaND4RyaeiwqyH9QYyE9M7Q39w&oe=62978E42)

Comment: I'm hoping to find two identical tandem breakers by matching up the specs on the old ones to what's available at the store.  This is all fairly new to me, so I'm trying to do as much research as possible before attempting the swap myself. Is there anything in particular about the text on the old breakers that I should have in mind when searching for a replacement? In case the picture doesn't show, the breakers read: Westinghouse BD 2020 R Type BRD 120/240 V AC CU/AL 60/75 C Wire HACR Type SWD Listed Cir Bkr 2 Pole Unit J 640 E7819 S 92 09 21

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure if your links are valid or not or what they're pointing to, but if you've got pics of the breakers, please edit your original question then use the "sun & mountain" button above the text edit box to embed the pics into the original question. Also, please include a picture of the ID label (brand, model number, etc.) on the inside of the panel. It's always possible that the existing breaker doesn't belong in the panel, so the panel is the source of truth on what breakers belong.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I added a photo of the breakers and I'll add a photo of the ID label shortly. It's the two inner breakers that I need to downgrade; the outer ones protect circuits for the washer and kitchen receptacles, respectively, so I need to keep them.

Comment: Photo of ID label added

Comment: I'm hoping the electricians among us can weigh in on the varieties of BR breakers out there, as well as the possibility of a MWBC without a handle tie and how that would impact a switch. You'll probably find that BD1520 breakers are either expensive or in short supply. If the stars line up, all you'll need is a tandem/piggyback 15 and a bit of wire moving, but that's above my pay grade.

Comment: OK, thanks.  It looks like BD1520 are available at Lowe's (<$15).  I watched a few videos on swapping breakers and it looks straightforward (shut off power to panel, remove cover, check for voltage, detach hot, pull and unhook the old breaker, hook and push the new breaker, reattach hot; etc.)  I just need to make sure I know which breaker(s) to use; and I need to be certain I'm not overlooking anything critical. I noticed all the neutral wires in my panel are tied together, separate from the breakers, so I'm guessing the neutrals don't come into play, but I need to verify that, as well.

Comment: P.S. I don't think I'm dealing with an MWBC, if I understand what you mean by that correctly. In my case, each breaker shuts off a specific group of receptacles/switches on it's given circuit independently.